# d3 change text bound to data

Tags: arrays, data-binding, d3.js

Conncerning the code below I have three questions,
which seem to be related to each other:

(1) I try to change the text of a single div, which was previously 
    bound as part of an array
 -> if the way I do it below (changing textContent directly),
 how can I get access to the data-array instead (is there an index available
 to adress the correct element of the data-array directly)?

(2) what happens if I bind an array of divs and then unbind single divs?
    will all divs  be unbound afterwards ? or does it result in a mix 
    of bound or unbound elements: is data[1] still bound, bout data[3] 
    not?

(3) why do the data not update if I change them (they do not update at all,
    neither if I assign something to textContent, nor if I do not:
    you can check this, if you click on another number but the 8: also in that case
    the array does not update)!

If the questions sound somehow unconnected please 
try the code first (click the numbers with the mouse, especially the "-8-"),
this should clarify what I mean a bit!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="d3.js"></script>
    <style>
        div.bar:hover {
            border: 1px solid yellow;
        }
        div.bar {
            width: 50px;
        }
    </style> 
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="labeledDiv">
    </div>

    <script>

    var data = [4,8,16,23,9];

    function mousedown() {
        var txt = d3.select(this).node().textContent;
        alert("text of this node is: " + txt);
        if (txt == "-8-") {
            d3.select(this).node().textContent = "hit!!!";
        }

        var id = d3.select(this).node().id;
        alert("id IS NOT:" + id);

        var x = "";
        for (i = 0;i<5;i++)  {
            data[i] = data[i]+1;
            x =  x + i + ": " + data[i] + " " ;
        }
        alert("x: " + x);

    }

    d3.select(".labeledDiv")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("div")
    .attr("class","bar")
    .text(function(d) { return "-" + d + "-";});

    d3.select(".labeledDiv")
    .selectAll("div")
    .on("mousedown",mousedown);

    </script>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) node has no property id (unless I set it manually)

(2) changing data-array needs an update function to be called:

```
function update() {
    d3.select(".labeledDiv")
    .selectAll("div")
    .text(function(d,i) { return "text: " + d + " " + data[i]; });
};

function mousedown() {
   //... same as above
   // and then after changing data:

    update();

}
```